# How to add parent class objects to derived list

Tags: c#, derived-class

I have `Node` class:

```
public class Node
{
  public ObservableCollection<Node> Childs {get;set;}
//some other properties
}
```

and derived class NodeSimple:

```
public class NodeSimple:Node
{
    public new ObservableCollection<Node> Childs {get;set;}//do some work
}
```

Then i have list of Node:

```
List<Node> nodeList=GetNodes();
```

and i want convert it to NodeSimple list:

```
List<NodeSimple> simpleList=new List<NodeSimple>();
foreach(var node in nodeList)
     simpleList.Add(node as NodeSimple);
```

But i have null at `node as NodeSimple`.
What i do wrong?
I just want to convert it.
Thank you!

Comment: NodeSimple is always a Node, but the opposite is not always true.

Comment: Should `Node nodeList=GetNodes();` actually be `List<Node> nodeList=GetNodes();`?

Comment: You cannot cast a base class to a derived class like that (it would only work if your base class variables are referencing derived class objects).  Instead you'd need to write code to convert one to the other.  But really why are you attempting to do this?

Comment: i need to change behavior of Node class: he has 'clever' Child properties, wich  check childs on Node by own (check childs at Childs property and filter it by some rules).

Comment: You can't add a `Node` to a list of `NodeSimple`, but you *can* check for null and skip adding those.

Comment: If `node as NodeSimple` returns `null`, then the object referenced by `node` is _not_ an instance of `NodeSimple`, and simply casting it to `NodeSimple` is prohibited. It is not clear from your question why you expect a non-null result there; did you not expect `nodeList` to contain something other than `NodeSimple` instances? Do you think you should be able somehow to convert instances of `Node` which are not `NodeSimple` instances? Without a good [mcve] it's impossible to fully understand your question, never mind provide a good, useful answer.